# how to load modal when click a link without refresh

Tags: php, events, laravel

I have index page with some  modal box.
these modal cause page become  very untidy and bad effect when page loaded.
Now this is my question,how can i load that modal when click that link without refresh,i do not have any modal in index page at first,by click i include that modal?
I use laravel 4 framework,some guys say it is possible by event in laravel,is it?

Comment: I think what you want to look into is [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

Comment: i know a little about ajax but is it possible with event in laravel????

Comment: You can't listen for a click event in the DOM with laravel. If you want data loaded into the page after the request has finished you need to do it asynchronously.

Comment: could you explain more???!and an example???thanks a lot